# How to detect dot (.), underscore(_) and dash(-) in regex

Tags: bash, regular-expression, ip-address

I need to process information dealing with IP address or folders containing information about an IP host.

I need a pattern that can identify (match) IP addresses, whether an actual url, name of folder or data file . For example

```
127.0.0.10
127-0-0-10
127_0_0_10
```

should all match. above. Is there any tokenizer regex to do this in bash?

Comment: Matching IP addresses with regex is [no easy task](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html).  How accurate should your match be?  Should it fail for an address of `0.0.0.0` or `10.10.10.256`?

Comment: how are you matching? with wildcards? with grep? with a bash `[[ =~ ]]` test?

Comment: IPv4 or IPv6? Or both?

Comment: "_I need a pattern that can identify (match) IP addresses, whether an actual url, name of folder or data file_". Pretty much the only thing that will match all these requirements is a full wildcard `.*`, at which point you might as well abandon any idea of matching with REs. Or did you mean to match just the IP address component _within_ those different types of string? Please be _precise_ when describing what you need. Ideally provide examples of the different matches required.

Comment: `127-0-0-10` isn't standard notation for an IPv4 address. Is this some sort of exception to the pattern matching requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regex seems to accomplish what you need:

```
\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])[-._](25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])[\-._](25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])[\-._](25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\b
```

---

```
$ cat test.txt
127.0.0.10
127-0-0-10
127_0_0_10
256_5_10_1
10-10-100-1
192.168.100.1
$ grep -E '\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])[-._](25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])[-._](25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])[-._](25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\b' test.txt
127.0.0.10
127-0-0-10
127_0_0_10
10-10-100-1
192.168.100.1
```

---

See https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html for an explanation of the regex.  I have simply modified the `\.`s with `[-._]` so that it will match `-`, `.`, or `_`.